# Code to get log4j2 property

Tags: java, log4j2

This is my log4j2.xml file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="runid">$${date:YYYYMMddHHmmssSSS}</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="File" fileName="D:\Users\Rich\Documents\TestData\PagemonTest12\LogRun\Log-${runid}.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

It creates a property called runid based on the current date and time.  How can I access runid (the created runid, not the text in the xml file) as a String in my Java 7 application?

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to get property from log4j2.xml:

```
if (ctx == null) {
  ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext();
  config = (XMLConfiguration) ctx.getConfiguration();
}
app = config.getStrSubstitutor().getVariableResolver()
  .lookup(Constants.CONF_APP_PROPERTIE);
```

Answer (score -1):

${bundle:br.com.domain.sadt.server.config:config.log.folder}

where:
- br.com.domain.sadt.server.config = your config.properties
- config.log.folder = key

to use in xml
${folder}